# Find all open handles or references to usb drive

Tags: windows, debugging, windbg

I'm analyzing a post-mortem kernel dump and I'm trying to identify all processes and filter drivers that may be referencing a USB storage drive or have handles open to it. I've tried examining all the open handles but even with limiting it to only File objects the data isn't manageable. So I navigated through the !object \ list to find the volume I'm looking for:

```
3: kd> !devobj fffffa8007169cd0
Device object (fffffa8007169cd0) is for:
 HarddiskVolume6 \Driver\volmgr DriverObject fffffa8006af2060
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 34 Type 00000007 Flags 00001050
Vpb fffffa8007168940 Dacl fffff9a10033a3c0 DevExt fffffa8007169e20 DevObjExt fffffa8007169f88 Dope fffffa80071688d0 DevNode fffffa800716b890 

3: kd> !vpb fffffa8007168940
Vpb at 0xfffffa8007168940
Flags: 0x1 mounted 
DeviceObject: 0xfffffa8008880030
RealDevice:   0xfffffa8007169cd0
RefCount: 34
Volume Label:
```

Is it possible to find what all of these 34 references are? 
Is there a simple method of identifying what is using any given volume from a memory dump?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesnt !devhandle on the devobject provide you any details ?

**kd> .shell -ci "!object \Device" grep -i harddisk**

```
xxxxxxxxxx
     20  849a8e20 Device        HarddiskVolume8
xxxxxxxx
```

**kd> !devobj 849a8e20**

```
Device object (849a8e20) is for:
 HarddiskVolume8 \Driver\volmgr DriverObject 851708b0
Current Irp 00000000 RefCount 5 Type 00000007 Flags 00003050
Vpb 8594de78 Dacl b0c8b8a4 DevExt 849a8ed8 DevObjExt 849a8fc0 Dope 8493ee10 DevNode 86643708 
ExtensionFlags (0000000000)  
Characteristics (0x00000001)  FILE_REMOVABLE_MEDIA  <--------
AttachedDevice (Upper) 866f04c8 \Driver\fvevol
Device queue is not busy.
```

**kd> !devhandles 849a8e20**

```
Checking handle table for process 0x84830ae8
Kernel handle table at 89601b80 with 636 entries in use
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

PROCESS 86479210  SessionId: 1  Cid: 05e8    Peb: 7ffdf000  ParentCid: 05b0
    DirBase: 7e28f2c0  ObjectTable: 94dcc900  HandleCount: 923.
    Image: explorer.exe

121c: Object: 84a03550  GrantedAccess: 00100081 Entry: adac3438
Object: 84a03550  Type: (848adde8) File
    ObjectHeader: 84a03538 (new version)
        HandleCount: 1  PointerCount: 2
        Directory Object: 00000000  Name: \ {HarddiskVolume8} <----

PROCESS 86479210  SessionId: 1  Cid: 05e8    Peb: 7ffdf000  ParentCid: 05b0
    DirBase: 7e28f2c0  ObjectTable: 94dcc900  HandleCount: 923.
    Image: explorer.exe

12ac: Object: 84a0a038  GrantedAccess: 00100081 Entry: adac3558
Object: 84a0a038  Type: (848adde8) File
    ObjectHeader: 84a0a020 (new version)
        HandleCount: 1  PointerCount: 2
        Directory Object: 00000000  Name: \ {HarddiskVolume8} <-----
```